# Resumable AES GCM in Python 3?

Tags: python, pickle, aes-gcm, pycryptodome, reentrancy

Is there an implementation of AES GCM for Python 3 which not only accepts piecewise messages, but also allows the working state of the cipher to be serialized, stored, and later resumed?

(I have an AES256-GCM stream, a key, and a nonce. The stream comes in to my Flask app as a series of messages, and I don't think my app will be able to run continuously for the entire time. I will lose the working-state of the ongoing crypto operation whenever the app terminates.)

I tried using Cryptodome.Cipher.AES in the GCM mode, which does allow piecewise operation through an update() / update_and_digest() mechanism, but I don't see a way to save the internal state and resume it later.

I tried pickling the AES object, but pickle complains that it can't serialize it because it is a module.

I am able to store the key and nonce, and maybe it's possible to periodically digest the message and store that, but It's not clear to me if that would help to reinstantiate an AES object and resume an operation.

Comment: Attempting to pickle each of the Cipher's attributes one by one, the thing that seems to cause the issue is `cipher._factory`. The `cipher._cipher` attribute seems to be problematic as well, as that gives a `cannot pickle '_cffi_backend._CDataBase' object` error.

Comment: I'm not sure I see anyway around this.  Could you avoid decrypting until you've received all the messages? Or alternatively, save the messages you've gotten so far that that you can easily put the decryptor back into the same state?  I've really never heard of anyone wanting to serialize a decryptor before, though you present a good use case.

Comment: Why not store the encrypted stream and decrypt the completed data? What is the typical size of the data to be encrypted? The GCM mode is not designed to encrypt huge data and decrypt any random parts of them. Consider using a disk encryption algorithm such as ESSIV for that case.

Comment: Despite the encrypted stream being up to 4 GB in length (the guideline limit based on key size) and spanning several seconds or minutes, the plaintext will contain various discrete events which I would like to present to the end-user in a timely fashion.

Comment: I understand your pain.  I've just never seen it before.  If you have any control over the protocol, you're just much better having the encryption restart with each message and a new IV.    Your current protocol is also a bit unsafe; there is no way of verifying the integrity of the message until you've received the final authentication tag, but you're already presented the user partial results based on a not-yet-authenticated message.  Very bad.